# Проблема с jsf авторизацией

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

Нашел как сделать авторизацию c помощью jsf (http://www.journaldev.com/7252/jsf-authentication-login-logout-database-example),
однако выходит это:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Я уже несколько месяцев не могу сделать, скажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка?

Я залил проект на git https://github.com/Kurmanbek777/JSF_Login_Logout

Вот класс (стектрейс ругается на строку `ps = con.prepareStatement("Select login, password from users where login = ? and password = ?");`) :

```
package com.journaldev.jsf.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.journaldev.jsf.util.DataConnect;

public class LoginDAO {

    public static boolean validate(String user, String password) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {
            con = DataConnect.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("Select login, password from users where login = ? and password = ?");
            ps.setString(1, user);
            ps.setString(2, password);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Login error -->" + ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            DataConnect.close(con);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

package com.journaldev.jsf.util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class DataConnect {

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/123", "postgresql", "root");
            return con;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Database.getConnection() Error -->"
                    + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection con) {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Вот стектрейс:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.journaldev.jsf.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.journaldev.jsf.dao.LoginDAO.validate(LoginDAO.java:18)
    at com.journaldev.jsf.beans.Login.validateUsernamePassword(Login.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 41 more
```

---

[image: Скриншот подключения к ДБ]
На скриншоте схема подключения к ДБ

Comment: Похоже на то, что `DataConnect.getConnection()` возвращает `null`. Поищите в логах сообщения начинающиеся с `Database.getConnection() Error`.

Comment: да, спасибо, посмотрел в логах.у меня не подключается база.Внизу я добавил класс подключения к ДБ, все правильно, но не работает...не могу понять

Comment: А пишет-то в логе что конкретно? В сообщении должна быть причина неудачи при подключении.

Comment: Info:   Database.getConnection() Error -->Ошибка при попытке подсоединения.

Comment: А вы можете на том же хосте, где выполняется ваша программа, войти в базу выполнив команду `psql -h localhost -U postgresql 123` и введя пароль "root"?

Comment: нет, в командной строке не получается, пароль не печатается в cmd,сейчас пытаюсь понять в чем проблема.

Comment: Это нормально, что не печатается. В утилитах родом из мира unix'ов так делается маскировка паролей. Просто жмите нужные клавиши в нужном порядке и нажимайте потом enter.

Comment: у меня Win10 и пароль вбиваю правильно.

Comment: У вас на скриншоте пользователь `postgres`, а в коде `postgresql`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, стыдно теперь....

Comment: Ничего страшного, все ошибаются.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте указать БД перед обращением к таблице

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("Select login, password from **123**.users where login = ? and password = ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.journaldev.jsf.util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class DataConnect {

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/123", "postgresql", "root");
            return con;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Database.getConnection() Error -->"
                    + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void close(Connection con) {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```